# Why doesn't Python want to access the second item of my 2-items list?

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to split an email address under the format jim.smith-royal@smth.edu or jim.smith@smth.edu into a name and a surname, so jim and smith, or jim and smith royal (with a space in between). (I am a beginner so I may not be doing it in the simplest way, but still).

```
for row in votants:
    mail = row[1]
    full_name = mail.split('@')[0]
    prenom = full_name.split('.')[0]

    #The code works until here, full_name.split gives me ['jim','smith'] and prenom gives me 'jim'

    pre_name = full_name.split('.')
    nom = pre_name[1]

    #The problem is until here, but I kept the rest of my code for anyone who might have the same objective as me

    try:
        nom = nom.split('-')[0] + " " + nom.split('-')[1]
    except Exception:
        pass
    row.append(prenom)
    row.append(nom)
```

Instead of giving me nom as 'smith', I get "IndexError: list index out of range".

Comment: You should check if ```full_name.split('.')``` returns or not. then do ```pre_name[1]``` there should be ```if pre_name: nom = pre_name[1]```

Comment: What do you think will happen if `mail` is "someone@example.com" ?

Comment: LIkely one of the e-mail addresses you are handling there does not have the "." separation. That would yield this error.

Comment: `nom` is equal to `smith`, which is only one element. In your `try` statement, you want to manipulate a second element (`nom.split('-')[1]`). This is `out of range` , so an error will occur.

Comment: Have you considered using a *regular expression* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

```
mail = "jim.smith@smth.edu"
full_name = mail.split('@')[0]
prenom = full_name.split('.')[0]

#The code works until here, full_name.split gives me ['jim','smith'] and prenom gives me 'jim'

pre_name = full_name.split('.')
nom = pre_name[1]

#The problem is until here, but I kept the rest of my code for anyone who might have the same objective as me


print(full_name);
print(pre_name);
print(nom);
print(prenom);
```

and it prints:

- jim.smith
- ['jim', 'smith']
- smith
- jim

Without any exceptions.

## Problem:

Like comments said: If no "." is used in name (before @), you are probably facing the indexOutOfRange Exception.

## Possible Solutions:

Surround it in if-else block:

```
if len(pre_name) >= 2
```

or use try-except:

```
try:
    nom = pre_name[1]
except IndexError:
    nom = pre_name[0];
```

or use:

```
if "." in full_name: 
    pre_name = full_name.split('.')
    nom = pre_name[1]
```

## General Debugging:

use `print()` earlier.

```
// works until here
pre_name = full_name.split('.')
print(pre_name) // if no '.' was used, you will see the array contains only 1 element
nom = pre_name[1] // problem here?
```

Comment: Thank you ! Turns out I had forgotten to remove the header (which wasn't split by a '.'), which stopped the program at the first attempt.

Comment: You should try to avoid at all cost using `except Exception` they make debugging very hard because they hide all unexpected bugs, just use the exception you actuelly expect `except IndexError`